# Stored procedure parameter error expecting

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this code block and I am not sure how to fix the error when I execute it.

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Dan_IPro_to_II]') AND type in (N'P', N'PK'))
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[Dan_IPro_to_II]
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE Dan_IPro_to_II 
    @ipro_db SYSNAME,
    @ipro_setid int,
    @II_setid int
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   DECLARE @table_name SYSNAME
   Declare @table_part VARCHAR(30)
   Declare @db SYSNAME

   DECLARE comp_cursor CURRSOR FOR
      SELECT TABLE_NAME 
      FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
      WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
        AND TABLE_NAME LIKE '%' + @ipro_setID + '' 
      ORDER BY TABLE_NAME

   OPEN COMP_CURSOR

   FETCH NEXT FROM COMP_CURSOR INTO @table_name

   SET @table_part = 'IPro_' + replace(@table_name,'_' + @ipro_setID,'')

   WHILE (@@fetch_status = 0 and @@error = 0 )
   BEGIN
        print 'Copying ' + @table_name

        EXEC ('if exists (select Table_Name from information_schema.tables where    table_name = ''' + @table_part + ''' ) DROP TABLE ' + @table_part )
        EXEC ('select * into ' + @table_part + ' FROM [' + @ipro_db + '].[dbo].' + @table_name  )

        FETCH NEXT FROM COMP_CURSOR INTO @table_name
    END

    print 'Completed Ipro Transfer ' +@db

    CLOSE COMP_CURSOR
    DEALLOCATE COMP_CURSOR
END
GO
```

This is the error I get when I execute the stored procedure:

> Msg 201, Level 16, State 4, Procedure Dan_IPro_to_II, Line 0
>   Procedure or function 'Dan_IPro_to_II' expects parameter '@ipro_db', which was not supplied.

I need to tell it where to find `@Ipro_db`, I think? Where would I put that? In the execute statement of the stored procedure?

Thanks for the help.

I tried talking them into importing or exporting the data but they don't have anyone who knows how to do that. They want it this way.

Thanks again for the help.

VBNewbie.

Comment: How are you calling this procedure? There are 3 inbound parameters. Are you providing them?

Comment: There is an export/import wizard built into SQL Server Management Studio which is far easier to work with than dynamic SQL in a cursor. The error message suggests you are executing the procedure and not specifying the correct parameters. How are you executing the stored procedure?

Comment: yes i know there is a function on export/import. there people dont know it and i tried to get them to do it that way. I am not sure what to pass for the parameters. i see what code calls for but not sure what to pass in executable. i think @Ipro_db = ipro database. Like that correct? i did not write code. someone else did. i modified what i found and partially understand what to do. i am use to the import/export function. Sorry cant be more helpful than that.

Comment: I call the stored procedure by executing it from right clicking on it. Obviously i need to write a script to call it in stored procedure wise. My question is. What database do i call. i have tried where it comes from - dbo.ipro90 but it does not like that argument. So i am stuck on that part. Sorry i am not good at this stored procedure part.

Comment: ipro90 is the database name? Just try that, so it'll end up as ipro90.dbo.[tablename] in the code. However, there's a DROP TABLE in there, so I'd be careful since you didn't write this.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this, I have changed few things in your code. Included conversion function to Int parameters. Keyword Cursor is misspelled.

```
IF EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM sys.objects
        WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Dan_IPro_to_II]')
            AND type IN (
                N'P'
                ,N'PK'
                )
        )
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[Dan_IPro_to_II]
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE Dan_IPro_to_II @ipro_db SYSNAME
    ,@ipro_setid INT
    ,@II_setid INT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @table_name SYSNAME
    DECLARE @table_part VARCHAR(30)
    DECLARE @db SYSNAME

    DECLARE comp_cursor CURSOR
    FOR
    SELECT TABLE_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
    --AND TABLE_NAME LIKE '%' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@ipro_setID) + ''
    ORDER BY TABLE_NAME

    OPEN COMP_CURSOR

    FETCH NEXT
    FROM COMP_CURSOR
    INTO @table_name

    SET @table_part = 'IPro_' + replace(@table_name, '_' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @ipro_setID), '')

    WHILE (
            @@fetch_status = 0
            AND @@error = 0
            )
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Copying ' + @table_name

        EXEC ('if exists (select Table_Name from information_schema.tables where    table_name = ''' + @table_part + ''' ) DROP TABLE ' + @table_part)

        EXEC ('select * into ' + @table_part + ' FROM [' + @ipro_db + '].[dbo].' + @table_name)

        FETCH NEXT
        FROM COMP_CURSOR
        INTO @table_name
    END

    PRINT 'Completed Ipro Transfer ' + @db

    CLOSE COMP_CURSOR

    DEALLOCATE COMP_CURSOR
END
GO

--Sample Procedure Call
EXEC Dan_IPro_to_II @ipro_db='SampleDB'
    ,@ipro_setid='1'
    ,@II_setid='1001'
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. when i run your executable part i get back an error on the conversion '%'. Which doesnt make sense since it is not part of it anymore. weird. Any suggestions on work around? Unless something else is happening. Error says line 26 which is the Order by clause.

Comment: Sorry my fault. I had a typo in my executable call. My apologies. It did run but got an 'Invalid object name' for one of the tables. Seems it doesnt have an underscore after table name. so it runs long. Looks like this - Ipro_AG_RT604190666.

Comment: Select my post if it best suits you.

Comment: I tried. i lost points because of editing my code wasnt up to par for certain people. Sheesh.

Comment: The stored procedure works but when i execute it via another script it does not copy any of the tables. That executable script works as well and i pass the parameters in. not sure why it doesnt copy any of the tables. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way I solved this problem as well. Thanks to @StackNewUser for help in getting this figured out.

USE [ImpactPro90]
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

```
DECLARE @table_name SYSNAME
DECLARE @table_part SYSNAME

DECLARE comp_cursor cursor FOR
    SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
    AND TABLE_NAME  LIKE '%_1604220600'  
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME

OPEN COMP_CURSOR

FETCH NEXT FROM COMP_CURSOR INTO @table_name
    SET @table_part = 'IPro_' + @table_name 
    WHILE (@@fetch_status = 0 and @@error = 0 )
BEGIN
   PRINT'Copying table ' + @table_name
   EXEC ('select * into ' +'[II_to_IIRP].[dbo].' + @table_name + ' FROM  [ImpactPro90].[dbo].' + @table_name  )
   PRINT 'Done copying ' + @table_name
   FETCH NEXT FROM COMP_CURSOR INTO @table_name
   PRINT 'Getting next table ' + @table_name
```

END
   CLOSE COMP_CURSOR
   DEALLOCATE COMP_CURSOR
   END